# Adding controller in non-mvc asp.net 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a big web form application in asp.net 4, I wanted to add a controller to the same, since it is just a class which implements Contoller interface, in global.asax I added:

```
protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    // mvc route
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

I then created a class:

```
namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class HomeController: Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Redirect("http://google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I hit the url:

http://localhost:54232/home/index

It givers a **resource cannot be found** error, but the same works for an asp.net mvc application

Comment: *I think you can do same think with webapi and that will work!*

Comment: Why are you even doing this? Does the webforms not work without controller?

Comment: @ekad It maps to .aspx page which invokes a page handler, I just want to invoke some function in class like we do using handlers/httpmodules, just trying out to find if this is an option too

Comment: http://rachelappel.com/integrating-aspnet-web-forms-and-aspnetmvc/

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc